# Tricky MySQL Insert and Update

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a shopping cart for my website.
When an user add something into the cart it should insert item_id and quantity into the items column in my DB.
The item column should hold a string like this:

```
1:5;6:2;13:1
```

item_id:quantity;item_id:quantity and so on

The insert part I already got, but when the user wants to view the cart, the string needs to be split into an array and fetch the items from another table

Array example:

```
1 => 5,
6 => 2,
13 = 1
```

I'v tried using spliti(";" $raw);
But didn't get what I wanted.

And the same thing when the user updates/deletes a product from the cart..
When the user updates/deletes a product, it must search through the string inside items and find the current place of the product.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please rethink your data model - storing '1:5;6:2;13:1' in a table is guaranteed to give you a lot of headache in the future when you try to access / modify your data.

Comment: Please don't write "[PHP][MySQL]" in the title. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are building your own cart do it correctly using a properly normalized schema. This means that you need to avoid "special" values which do more than 1 thing at the same time.

So the obvious improvement here is to have:

```
table users:
    id
    ...

table products:
    id
    ...

table cart_items:
    user_id
    product_id
    quantity
```

[CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) queries will be very simple to implement then and also very fast.

Comment: Thanks, used to do it like this before, just wanted to try it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't think it's a good idea to have your items as a string in your order/cart table. You run into a lot of problems this way (you've already run into a couple).

It's better to have a `hasMany` relationship. Something along the likes of the design shown below is ideal.

```
Order Table : id, date, total, more, fields
OrderItem Table : id, order_id, item_id, value, more, fields //item_id is a ref to your Items/Product table
```

This allows you to link your items to your orders properly and you can do your inserts and updates without a problem.

As for your current question, you need to split it twice

```
$items = 1:5;6:2;13:1;
$items_arr = explode(';', $itemrs);
$new_items = array();
foreach ($iterms_arr as $item) {
  $pieces = explode(':', $item);
  //might want to do some error checking on whether the indices exist
  $new_items[$pieces[0]] = $pieces[1];
}
```